# How to sleep in a worker thread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am creating an example to understand threads in Qt and want my worker thread to sleep for 1 second between each increment so I can see the debug output. But the sleep makes my main GUI thread non-responsive.

Here is my slot functoin in `OddCounter` class.

```
void OddCounter::count()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        counter += 2;

        qDebug() << counter;

        QThread::sleep( 1 );
    }
}
```

My mainwindow class which calls this thread is:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    oddCounter = new OddCounter;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(startOddCounter()), evenCounter, SLOT(count()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    OddCounter oddCounter;

    oddCounter.moveToThread( &thread );

    thread.start();

    emit startOddCounter();
}
```

The problem is when I press the button, the counter works and displays the next increment after each second passed but the mainwindow is non responsive all this time! This is not right! I want my mainwindow to be responsive and only the thread should sleep. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in your code: you are creating another `OddCounter` which you move to the different thread but your original `oddCounter` to which the signal is connected still lives in the main thread. You should change your code to this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    oddCounter->moveToThread( &thread );
    thread.start();
    emit startOddCounter();
}
```